# start activity but in background

Tags: java, c++, android, c

My application will launch a new activity (say calculator) using intents.

My requirement is: Is there any way to start the new activity in background (not in foreground)?

Can you suggest any solution?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short version : Use threads.

Not-so-long version : [read about threads](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do exactly? Depending on that, you have several options:

- You can use an AsyncTask
- You can use a local Service
- You can use a remote Service
- You can use a Thread

Answer (score 0):

Use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to receive the Intent and start [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/app/Service.html) or Thread do what you want to do.